# For Loop is not running,

Tags: java

My for loop in my code is being ignored,  I tested it without the if statement, and still the for loop doesn't output anything when I call it from the main method.

```
public void searchBatsmenID(int ID){

   for (Batsmen check : batsmen) {
       exists = false;
       if (check.id == ID && ID!=0){
           System.out.println("Player ID: " + check.id);
           System.out.println("Name: " + check.name);
           System.out.println("Age: " + check.age);
           System.out.println("Number of matches played: " + check.matches);
           System.out.println("Runs scored: " + check.runs);
           System.out.println("");
           exists = true;

       }
    }
```

Comment: If size of batsmen is zero then your for loop will not executes

Comment: How do you KNOW it is not running?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to know the issue. Provide a [mcve]. (By the way, it is sufficient to check `ID != 0` once instead of doing it in the for-loop.)

Comment: Have you noticed that you reset exists to false at each iteration? this is equivalent to testing only the last element.

Comment: print the objects , arrays/list's lengths that are using in your program if you are not sure what is the problem. Once you have done this step, learn more about IDE and Debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not getting error,there are 2 possible reason for your **For Loop** not being able to run...

1>. There is no element in your **batsmen**,i.e its size is zero.To check for this,print something before your **if** statement.

2>.if (check.id == ID && ID!=0) is also false.